# Sigma Complex vs Resonance Structure

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the difference between a sigma complex state of a Bezene and the resonance structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a positive charge is conjugated in the ring,it is called ***sigma complex.***

The ***resonance structure*** comprises of no such excess charge, only pi electron clouds

Comment: [Please check out how I edited the MathJax of this post](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52335). Please **do not** add `\ce{...}` into every mathematical expression like a robot.

Comment: I'm sorry, will take care from next time